# Topology on the compact supported smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-topology

The topology of $C^\infty_c(U)$ with $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined via the topology of $C^\infty(U)$ via a direct limit topology: you take an exhausting family of compact sets $K_i$ ($K_i \subset K_{i+1 }$ ) whose union is $U$, then take the induced topology on each of the $C^\infty(K_i)$ and take the inductive direct limit topology.

My question is: What is wrong with just taking directly the relative (induced) topology in $C^\infty_c(U)$ coming from the one in $C^\infty(U)$?

Comment: What would be your topology on $C^\infty(R^n)$?

Comment: The topology on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is that given by the family of seminorms $p_{\alpha,K}(f) = sup_{x \in K} |\partial^\alpha f(x)|$ where $K$ runs over all the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Then the result will not be a topology Invariants under diffeomorphisms. If this does not bother you, then fell free to use it.

Comment: @inquisitor Those "semi norms" can be infinite.

Comment: If you take the subspace topology induced by $C^{\infty}(U)$, then $C_c^{\infty}(U)$ is a dense subspace of $C^{\infty}(U)$. That's not so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as  Daniel Fischer is saying, the problem is that with that topology $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ would not be complete. In dimension one take $U=\mathbb{R}$, and consider
a function $\phi\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with support in $[0,1]$ such
that $\phi>0$ in $(0,1)$. Then the sequence 
$$
\phi_{n}(x):=\phi(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}\phi(x-2)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\phi(x-n),\quad
x\in\mathbb{R},
$$
is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the topology induced by the one in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ but its limit does not have compact support, and so it does not belong to
$C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.